# Special charecters on non english keyboard

Tags: arduino, ide, arduino-ide

I needed some special charecters to be printed on cmd with Keyboard.h, but i dont have a English layout keyboard,ive got a Estoninan layout because im from Estonia. Lets get to the point!
Ive triend every special key but i havent got the \ key yet, anyone knows how can i get it?

Board used: Arduino Pro Micro

Currently got special charecters:

```
! = !
~ = ~~
" = Ä
# = #
¤ = +15708
% = %
& = /
/ = -
( = )
) = =
= = ´´
? = _
Õ = +15467
Ü = +15460
Ä = +15484
Ö = +15466
* = (
_ = ?
: = Ö
; = ö
> = :
@ = "
£ = +15709
$ = ¤
€ = +32084
{ = Ü
[ = ü
] = õ
} = Õ
\ = '
§ = +15705
½ = +15683
ž = +14914
| = *
< = ;
š = +14943
ˇ = +13433
´ = +15692
+ = `
` = ˇ
ˇ = +13433
' = ä
ü = +15428
õ = +15435
ö = +15434
ä = +15452
- = +
. = .
, = ,
```

Comment: What does this have to do with Arduino?  You just have a list of code points. `\` is +U005C or 92 in the Basic Latin code page.

Comment: its Arduino IDE

Answer (score 0):

```
Keyboard.press(KEY_LEFT_ALT);
Keyboard.press(KEY_LEFT_CTRL);
Keyboard.press('_');
```

to get Backslash